# Installation of SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, business-intelligence, bids

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

This consists of the configuration tools (SQL server configuration manager, SQL Error and usage Reporting, SQL Server Surface area configuration, Reporting Services configuration) and SQL Server Management Studio.

However, I don't find SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio.

How can it be installed?

Is it available online as a freeware download?

Comment: What Edition of SQL Server 2005 did you install?

Comment: How to find the edition? I have downloaded it from internet.

Comment: @Sheetal: Query: SELECT @@Version

Answer (score 22):

It sounds like you have installed SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, which does not include SSIS or the Business Intelligence Development Studio.

BIDS is only provided with the (not free) Standard, Enterprise and Developer Editions.

**EDIT**

This information was correct for SQL Server 2005. Since SQL Server 2014, Developer Edition has been free. BIDS has been replaced by SQL Server Data Tools, a free plugin for Visual Studio (including the free Visual Studio Community Edition).

Comment: You are probably right about this, but do you have any link where this information is published? I really can't find this on msdn..

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx - see the Business Intelligence section.

Comment: Actually, Developer is free, but not for production.

Comment: @gary - thanks for pointing this out. The licensing model has changed a bit in the 8 years (!) since this answer was first posted.

Answer (score 8):

If you have installed SQL 2005 express edition and want to install BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) then go to here [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=3C856B93-369F-4C6F-9357-C35384179543&displaylang=en)

This has an option to install BIDS on my machine, and is the only way l could get hold of BIDS for SQL Server 2005 express edition.

Also this package l think has also allowed me to install both BIDS 2005 & 2008 express edition on the same machine.

Comment: Even though you'll have BIDS, you will only be able to use it to design reports as SQL Server Express Edition does not come with the SSIS or SSAS servers.  Even the SSRS server is only available in the "... with advanced services" Express Edition.

Comment: Probably nobody will see this new comment on an old post, but maybe it'll help somebody. Make sure when you install the core SQL Server components that you don't install any of the Client Components. That way when you install the Toolkit afterward you can tell it to install all components and you should get a clean install. I learned this by installing SQL Server 2005 Express with SP2 including Client Components, then went to install BIDS but it couldn't overwrite the already installed Client Components since they were a newer version.

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx

> Business Intelligence Development Studio is Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 with additional project types that are specific to SQL Server business intelligence. Business Intelligence Development Studio is the primary environment that you will use to develop business solutions that include Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services projects. Each project type supplies templates for creating the objects required for business intelligence solutions, and provides a variety of designers, tools, and wizards to work with the objects.

If you already have Visual Studio installed, the new project types will be installed along with SQL Server.

[More Information](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/80f2c22b-ee8e-44d6-b578-70cd6e70abb8)

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 actually installs the project for Visual Studio 2005, not 2008.  On my machine, the BI Studio link directs to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and posted the answer in *[Can't run Business Intelligence Development Studio, file is not found](http://webtackle.com/portal/BLOG/tabid/152/EntryID/2/Default.aspx)*.

I had this same problem. I am running .NET framework 3.5, SQL Server 2005, and Visual Studio 2008. While I was trying to run SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio the icon was grayed out and the devenv.exe file was not found.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Start /wait setup.exe /qb  ADDLOCAL=SQL_DTS,Client_Components,Connectivity,SQL_Tools90,SQL_WarehouseDevWorkbench,SQLXML,Tools_Legacy,SQL_Documentation,SQL_BooksOnline
```

Based off this TechNet Article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.90).aspx