# please any one provide sql server 2005 BIDS software to install in my pc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Provide sql server 2005 BIDS software to install in my pc. Is there any free download for this software?

Comment: clarify what BIDS means?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150192/install-sql-server-business-intelligence-development-studio

Comment: same as @inSane possible duplicate

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for SQL Server, visit the [SQL Server Download](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/get-sql-server/try-it.aspx) page. Find the SKU that's right for you!