# Install Business Intelligence studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssrs-2008, bids

I need to work on SSRS and for that I would need BIDS. I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition with Advanced features, also I have VS2008 installed.

How can I get BIDS installed on my machine?

Comment: Hello Pramodtech have you seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150192/installation-of-sql-server-business-intelligence-development-studio) here on the site, think that could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [SQL Server 2008 Express With Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22973) in order to get the BIDS extensions into Visual Studio 2008.