# BIDS installation with SSIS , SSRS and SSAS on SQL Express 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

I want SQL Server 2005 Express in my machine so that I can have a local database (not allowed to install standard or enterprise))and at the same time should be able to create projects for SSRS, SSIS and SSAS in BIDS.
I saw this post :
[Installation of SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150192/installation-of-sql-server-business-intelligence-development-studio)

there is a comment by Yohan saying..
"Probably nobody will see this new comment on an old post, but maybe it'll help somebody. Make sure when you install the core SQL Server components that you don't install any of the Client Components. That way when you install the Toolkit afterward you can tell it to install all components and you should get a clean install. I learned this by installing SQL Server 2005 Express with SP2 including Client Components, then went to install BIDS but it couldn't overwrite the already installed Client Components since they were a newer version"

This has actually helped me to get a direction for my issue.
However to confirm this , I went through many other posts which says once we install the Toolkit, we can design only SSRS reports in BIDS and not SSIS and SSAS.
It is ok if I dont get integration services and analysis services running on my mahcine. However I should be able to design them, i.e create BI projects.

what if I intsall SQL Express 2005 server components and then SQL Server 2005 client components?

Answer (score 0):

MsSQL server Express does not support SSRS!!!

What you propably mean is Express with advanced features.

Depending on the version of MsSQL server the corresponding BIDs will install.

The Business Intelligence studio is being installed along with the project templates for SSRS, SSIS and SSAS. If the Ms SQL version does not support the technology then the projects are unavailable (That is true for MsSQL 2008 and for the Data Tools of MsSQL 2010).

If you have another version of BIDs that you want to install then you should go to Control Panel ->(Add/Remove Programs in older windows or Programs and Features in newer) and choose to uninstall the MsSQL 2005. Choose remove and when you reach the features choose the BIDs studio.

After uninstalling this version of BIDs you can normally install the newer one along with its' BIDs.